# How can i use input().split() effectively to take at least 2 inputs from user in one line?

Tags: python

I was reading an article about python and i saw **input().split()**.I think,I can take multiple inputs from users with thatAnd I wrote this code.

```
a,b = input("Enter your number").split()
print(a,b)
```

But I got confused because whenever I try to run this code I got this error:

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

So,How can i take multiple inputs with that or can i?

Comment: If you got that error, you likely didn't supply two whitespace-separated numbers. We can't say though without knowing what you entered.

Comment: hmmm okey I get it.As you said,I hadn't added whitespace.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you probably typed just one number on the line,
and the error was raised because you expect 2 (a and b)

You should type both numbers on the same line, then enter.

You can change your code to accept any number of numbers,
and store them in a list:

```
res = input("Enter your numbers:").split()
print(*res)   ## prints the list content
for r in res: ## prints number one by one and one per line
    print(r)
```

result:

```
Enter your numbers: 12 13 14
12 13 14
12
13
14
```

Comment: your welcome, you can accept it is good for your.